# Tensorflow only one GPU active at a time in MULTI GPU training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, gpu, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN model using data parallelism mechanism. I am posting a code snippet of train method for simplicity,

```
def train_model(file_loc='', data_details='', epochs='',checkpoint='', learning_rate=1e-5):
    train_initializer = data_details['train_it_init']
    test_initializer = data_details['test_it_init']
    iterator = data_details['iterator']
    
    batch_list = [iterator.get_next()  for _ in range(NUM_GPUS)]

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        num_class=14
        tower_grads = []
        tower_losses = []
        opt =  tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
        dropout_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        for i in range(NUM_GPUS):
            with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
                with tf.device('/gpu:{}'.format(i)), tf.name_scope('tower_{}'.format(i)) as scope:
                    xbatch, ybatch = batch_list[i]
                    total_loss = tower_loss(scope, xbatch, ybatch, dropout_rate=dropout_rate)
                    tower_grads.append(opt.compute_gradients(total_loss))

        avg_grads = average_gradients(tower_grads)
        train_op = opt.apply_gradients(avg_grads)
```

I am trying to use 4 gpus (NUM_GPUS) but the problem is that only 1 gpu active at a time. It seems every GPU is doing their job but in a sequential matter. I cannot figure out why it is behaving like this way. I am using dataset api and iterator and iterator initializer are in data_details dictionary (tested, working) and model inference is called inside the tower_loss(..) method call under specific variable and name scope. Any suggestion would be really helpful.
My GPU usages are like below,
[gpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeyiG.png) [image: gpu usage]